# Primary key violation constraint

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, ado.net

```
string sqlInsert = "Insert into account_details(
     account_number,
     account_type,
     transfer_access_code,
     account_balance,
     customer_id) 
SELECT 
     account_number,
     account_type,
     transfer_access_code,
     account_balance,
     customer_id 
from customer_details";
```

This query just takes data from customer details(table1) and insert's it in other table2(account_details)

when this query is fired for first time it works fine

but when fired second time it show error 
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_account_details'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.account_details'.

any idea to skip existing data in (account_details)table1 and inserting new data in next row

Comment: what is the primary key?

Comment: customer_id in customer_details table and account_number in account details table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a `LEFT JOIN` allows you to exclude all the rows that are already present in the `account details` table. An alternative to this (and probably even faster) is using a `NOT EXISTS`.

using a `LEFT JOIN`

```
INSERT INTO account_details (
    account_number
    , account_type
    , transfer_access_code
    , account_balance
    , customer_id) 
SELECT  account_number
        , account_type
        , transfer_access_code
        , account_balance
        , customer_id 
FROM    customer_details cd
        LEFT OUTER JOIN account_details ad ON ad.Account_number = cd.account_number
WHERE   ad.account_number IS NULL
```

using a `NOT EXISTS`

```
INSERT INTO account_details (
    account_number
    , account_type
    , transfer_access_code
    , account_balance
    , customer_id) 
SELECT  account_number
        , account_type
        , transfer_access_code
        , account_balance
        , customer_id 
FROM    customer_details cd
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT   * 
          FROM     account_details 
          WHERE    account_number = cd.account_number)
```

Answer (score 4):

assuming Account_Number is the primary key, this should work

```
string sqlInsert = "Insert into account_details(
     account_number,
     account_type,
     transfer_access_code,
     account_balance,
     customer_id) 
SELECT 
     cd.account_number,
     cd.account_type,
     cd.transfer_access_code,
     cd.account_balance,
     cd.customer_id 
from customer_details cd
left outer join account_details ad
    on cd.account_number = ad.account_number
where ad.account_number is NULL";
```

Comment: +1 because I know how annoying it is to be beaten by a few seconds. (And it is a good answer)

Comment: Thanks for all the support folks. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO account_details (ad.account_number, ad.account_type, 
    ad.transfer_access_code, ad.account_balance, ad.customer_id) 
SELECT cd.account_number, cd.account_type, 
    cd.transfer_access_code, cd.account_balance, cd.customer_id
FROM customer_details cd
LEFT OUTER JOIN account_details ad 
    ON cd.account_number = ad.account_number 
WHERE ad.account_number is NULL
```